# nextjs components fetching data

Tags: next.js

this tutorial allows me to fetch data from a page. How can a component fetch data instead?

I have the  component that I want to fetch data from. How can I do this?

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#server-side-rendering

Answer (score 2):

You can use fetch data by using useEffect. On the other hand, you can fetch data from parent component and pass data to child component.

```
const Component = props => {
   // You can get data from parent component.
   const parentData = props.parentData

   useEffect(() => {
     // Fetch Data here when component first mounted
   }, [])
}
```

Comment: Does that mean the correct way in nextjs to get a logo into the layout is to pass it everytime you use the layout? Like so: 

export default function PageName({ logo }) {
  return (
    <SiteLayout logo={logo}>
      // content
    </SiteLayout>
  );
}

It feels a bit strange to have to pass that prop on every page.

Comment: If your logo is different across every page, I think you should pass it by `props` in every pages. On the other hands, if your logo is same across all pages, you can just define the logo in `SiteLayout` component only.

Comment: The problem is with defining it in SiteLayout is it's not statically generated. If hard-coded it loads after page generation. If passed as a prop each time I get the static generation, but isn't nice code.

Answer (score 2):

there is a new hook that NextJs provide it. this is SWR package

The team behind Next.js has created a React hook library for data fetching called SWR. It is highly recommended if you are fetching data on the client-side. It handles caching, revalidation, focus tracking, refetching on intervals, and more.

sample:

```
import useSWR from 'swr'

const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then((res) => res.json())

function Profile() {
  const { data, error } = useSWR('/api/profile-data', fetcher)

  if (error) return <div>Failed to load</div>
  if (!data) return <div>Loading...</div>

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data.name}</h1>
      <p>{data.bio}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

see the document:

[Client-side data fetching with SWR](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/client-side)

Answer (score 1):

For example. First create login.js page in pages folder and call api and in login.js than pass data to logincomponent.js file in component folder. It's proper way to load data in component in Next.js .
Other way is use UNSAFE_componentWillMount in component to call api.